# Every radical is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$a$ is an ideal of $A$.  $$f:A\to A/a,\ \  x∈r(a)$$

**r(a) is a prime ideal?**

*proof 1:*

$x^n\in a$ for some $n \Rightarrow (x+a)^n\in a$ for some $n \Rightarrow f(r(a))=\text{nil-radical}$ in $f(a) \Rightarrow r(a)$ is a prime ideal. (Since nil-radical is a prime ideal)

*proof 2:*

$x^n\in a$ for some $n \Rightarrow  (xb)^n\in a$ for some $n$ ,$b\notin r(a) \Rightarrow r(a)$ is a prime ideal

I must be doing something wrong. Can someone fix the proof?

Comment: It's not true in general. Take $k[x,y]$ and $(xy)$.

Comment: It is true that every radical is [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime_ideal), that is, an intersection of prime ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for proof 1: Nilradical is not a prime ideal it is intersection of all prime ideals.
for proof 2: To prove $r(a)$ is prime you should prove: $b\notin r(a)$ and $x\notin r(a)$ which is not true

Comment: Nilradical is not a prime ideal? $a,b \notin \text{nilradical}$ ⇒ $(ab)^n=(a^n)(b^n)≠0~for~every~n$⇒$ab \notin \text{nilradical}$⇒
"$a,b \notin \text{nilradical}⇒ab \notin \text{nilradical}$"

Comment: @amateur: it is possible that $(a^n)≠0$ and $(b^n)≠0$ but $(a^n)(b^n)=0$

Comment: Oh,there exist some nonzero zero divisor.Thanks.